# Can't put data into database,PHP

Tags: php, database

Someone help me, because I'm really confused as to why this sample code won't put data into database. Yes, it can connect onto the server successfully but it won't put data into the database table, help and please explain. Thank you in advance.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <form method='post' action='#'>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Username</td><td><input type='text' name='username'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Password</td><td><input type='password' name='password'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td><td><input type='submit' value='Login' name='button'/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['button']))
    {
    $u_nam = $_POST['username'];
    $pw = $_POST['password'];
    echo $u_nam;
    echo $pw;
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost','root', '');
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo 'Connected successfully';
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db('test', $link);
    if (!$db_selected) {
        die ('Can\'t use for: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO user VALUES(NULL,'$u_nam', '$pw')";
    mysql_query($query);
    mysql_close($link);
    }
    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If you're new to PHP and MySQL, you should seriously consider *not* using any of the functions you come across starting with `mysql_`. Try find tutorials that use PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: @Guru:
I'm using notepad++ ,so I really can't point out what the error is. All I know is it won't insert/put data unto the database table which is named 'user'.

Comment: @Marty:
Thank you for the advice..and yes, I new to this thing ^_^

Comment: have you problem  insert data in database?

Comment: show me your db table columns first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**your insert code:**   `$query = "INSERT INTO user VALUES(NULL,'$u_nam', '$pw')";`

1:why you are inserting NULL?if the column is primary key than it will through error and your data will not be inserted.its better idea to use column name and leave and dont put any any value for column which is primary key and auto increment.

like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO user(a,b) VALUES('$u_nam', '$pw')";
```

2:**try to debug:**

```
use mysql_error().
```

like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO user VALUES('$u_nam', '$pw')";

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: OMG it work...BUT why would it duplicates the data in the table?ah I mean I only entered one data but then it duplicate.

Comment: @ChocoLover you might be pressing the submit button twice :)

Comment: no I only press it once mmmm I think its because of the mysql_query($)query... anyways thank you ^_^

Answer (score -2):

**Try this code:**

```
<body>
<form method='post' action='#'>

<table>
<tr>
<td>Username</td><td><input type='text' name='username'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td><td><input type='password' name='password'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td><td><input type='submit' value='Login' name='button'/></td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$u_nam = $_POST['username'];
$pw = $_POST['password'];

echo $u_nam;
echo $pw;


$link = mysql_connect('localhost','root', '');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';


$db_selected = mysql_select_db('test', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use for: ' . mysql_error());
}

$query = "INSERT INTO user VALUES('$u_nam', '$pw')";

mysql_query($query);

mysql_close($link);

}
?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't know whether this will work or not, but if it does there's nothing here to help the OP understand why this is a solution.

Comment: it is still the same -_- . . . what did you edit on it

Comment: have you problem insert data in database?

Comment: ah I think I now see that code you changed..it worked so thanks